# Remove part of string after third occurrence of certain character

Tags: php

I have a special case where I have a whole range of different strings in an array.

What I need is to remove last part of a string at the third occurrence of /.

Example:

Accessories / Mens Accessories / Bags Wallets / Messenger Bags /

So here I want to remove: Messenger Bags /

How is this possible with PHP - remember I have a lot of different strings! So I can't take the position as it's different each time.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Start reading: http://php.net/explode

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Here you will have 4 elements    
$parts = explode ('/', $string);

//this will glue the first 3 elements
list ($first, $second, $third) = $parts;

//Here you can see the desired result
var_dump (implode ('/',array($first, $second, $third)));
```

### Output

```
string 'Accessories / Mens Accessories / Bags Wallets ' (length=46)
```